# Performance of Google's Go?

Tags: performance, go

So has anyone used Google's Go?  I was wondering how the mathematical performance (e.g. flops) is compared to other languages with a garbage collector... like Java or .NET?

Has anyone investigated this?

Comment: I clicked on this question just to see what a go
question looked like... :D

Comment: @VladimirF It looks like Fortran right? :)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The Go [math package](http://golang.org/pkg/math/) is largely written in assembler for performance.

Benchmarks are often unreliable and are subject to interpretation. For example, Robert Hundt's paper [Loop Recognition in C++/Java/Go/Scala](http://research.google.com/pubs/pub37122.html) looks flawed. The Go blog post on [Profiling Go Programs](http://blog.golang.org/2011/06/profiling-go-programs.html) dissects Hundt's claims.

Comment: I can't find any evidence that Go's math package is written in assembler. Even the link above doesn't take me to assembly code.

Comment: some googling takes me to this http://code.google.com/p/go/source/browse/#hg%2Fsrc%2Fpkg%2Fmath
seems like the answer is right.

Comment: @MrOrdinaire's link got obsoleted and now transtales to https://github.com/golang/go/tree/master/src/math where one can see indeed a lot of (very short) assembly source files. Whether that's a proof of efficiency I cannot definitely tell.

Comment: Go is on Github now, see: https://github.com/golang/go/tree/master/src/math

Answer (score 82):

Theoretical performance: The theoretical performance of pure Go programs is somewhere between C/C++ and Java. This assumes an advanced optimizing compiler and it also assumes the programmer takes advantage of all features of the language (be it C, C++, Java or Go) and refactors the code to fit the programming language.

Practical performance (as of July 2011): The standard Go compiler (5g/6g/8g) is currently unable to generate efficient instruction streams for high-performance numerical codes, so the performance will be lower than C/C++ or Java. There are multiple reasons for this: each function call has an overhead of a couple of additional instructions (compared to C/C++ or Java), no function inlining, average-quality register allocation, average-quality garbage collector, limited ability to erase bound checks, no access to vector instructions from Go, compiler has no support for SSE2 on 32-bit x86 CPUs, etc.

Bottom line: As a rule of thumb, expect the performance of numerical codes implemented in pure Go, compiled by 5g/6g/8g, to be 2 times lower than C/C++ or Java. Expect the performance to get better in the future.

---

Practical performance (September 2013): Compared to older Go from July 2011, Go 1.1.2 is capable of generating more efficient numerical codes but they remain to run slightly slower than C/C++ and Java. The compiler utilizes SSE2 instructions even on 32-bit x86 CPUs which causes 32-bit numerical codes to run much faster, most likely thanks to better register allocation. The compiler now implements function inlining and escape analysis. The garbage collector has also been improved but it remains to be less advanced than Java's garbage collector. There is still no support for accessing vector instructions from Go.

Bottom line: The performance gap seems sufficiently small for Go to be an alternative to C/C++ and Java in numerical computing, unless the competing implementation is using vector instructions.

Comment: This is very interesting, can you offer us an update to your remarks for Go in today's context?

Comment: Very insightful answer. Thanks!

Comment: There exist libraries which allow you to do vector math in Go actually, https://github.com/go-hep/math3, being the one that I found.

Comment: Your answer is quite informative. Since your update in 2013, go has updated to go1.4. Would you please give an update for the new Go?

Comment: @Atom thank you for the answer! Could you please update it? :) It is very interesting to see the progress but I did not find any good sources of gathered information about Go performance.

Answer (score 15):

You're actually asking several different questions. First of all, Go's math performance is going to be about as fast as anything else. Any language that compiles down to native code (which arguably includes even JIT languages like .NET) is going to perform extremely well at raw math -- as fast as the machine can go. Simple math operations are very easy to compile into a zero-overhead form. This is the area where compiled (including JIT) languages have a advantage over interpreted ones.

The other question you asked was about garbage collection. This is, to a certain extent, a bit of a side issue if you're talking about heavy math. That's not to say that GC doesn't impact performance -- actually it impacts quite a bit.  But the common solution for tight loops is to *avoid* or *minimize* GC sweeps. This is often quite simple if you're doing a tight loop -- you just re-use your old variables instead of constantly allocating and discarding them. This can speed your code by several orders of magnitude.

As for the GC implementations themselves -- Go and .NET both use mark-and-sweep garbage collection. Microsoft has put a lot of focus and engineering into their GC engine, and I'm obliged to think that it's quite good all things considered. Go's GC engine is a work in progress, and while it doesn't *feel* any slower than .NET's architecture, the Golang folks insist that it needs some work. The fact that Go's specification disallows destructors goes a long way in speeding things up, which may be why it doesn't seem that slow.

Finally, in my own anecdotal experience, I've found Go to be **extremely fast**. I've written very simple and easy programs that have stood up in my own benchmarks against highly-optimized C code from some long-standing and well-respected open source projects that pride themselves on performance.

The catch is that not *all* Go code is going to be efficient, just like not *all* C code is efficient. You've got to build it correctly, which often means doing things differently than what you're used to from other languages. The [profiling blog post](http://blog.golang.org/2011/06/profiling-go-programs.html) mentioned here several times is a good example of that.

Comment: You are wrong, with the performance on numerics. There can be worlds between the output of different code generators. And Go's code generator is very simple but have a fast runtime library if this is all you need.

Comment: @Lothar: There can be, of course. But as a rule, there isn't.

Answer (score 2):

Google did a study comparing Go to some other popular languages (C++, Java, Scala).  They concluded it was not as strong performance-wise:

https://days2011.scala-lang.org/sites/days2011/files/ws3-1-Hundt.pdf

Quote from the Conclusion, about Go:

> Go offers interesting language features, which also allow for a concise and standardized notation. The compilers for this language are still immature, which reﬂects in both performance and binary sizes.

Comment: That study was completely bunk as the test code was terrible. A little code optimization decreased the run-time from 56 seconds down to 3.8 seconds (Actually faster than the C++ version). http://blog.golang.org/2011/06/profiling-go-programs.html

Comment: The study was implementing the algorithm naively with all programming languages, on purpose. The golang blog post does not say it's flawed.

Comment: I won't say that it was "Google" which did the study. Saying that seems to indicate as if even the "Go" team was involved in the paper. That was not the case. As pointed by @tylerl the blog post shows that with some optimization both the run-time and memory consumption could be decreased. @Elazar Please read this article: http://www.theregister.co.uk/2011/07/01/go_v_cpluplus_redux/print.html